System message or unwanted remote access?
Program message with help or unwanted remote service access?
I was using the tor service and multitor from from github at the same time with the command
multitor --init 2 --user debian-tor --socks-port 9000 --control-port 9900 --proxy privoxy
and after checking the /etc/tor folder I found the  --proxy file with the below message.
─$ cat ' --proxy'
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a SOCKS Proxy, Not An HTTP Proxy</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a SOCKs proxy, not an HTTP proxy.</h1>
<p>
It appears you have configured your web browser to use this Tor port as
an HTTP proxy.
</p><p>
This is not correct: This port is configured as a SOCKS proxy, not
an HTTP proxy. If you need an HTTP proxy tunnel, use the HTTPTunnelPort
configuration option in place of, or in addition to, SOCKSPort.
Please configure your client accordingly.
</p>
<p>
See <a href="https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html">https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html</a> for more information.
</p>
</body>
</html>

Any clarification, help with understanding what happening, because for my opinion it’s weird getting a message in the system folder about what’s going on with my service or that mulitor program? Maybe I'm just missing the point. But would like know your ideas, and clarifications.

This just looks like a standard error message that was output to a file because the command couldn't understand the --proxy argument

But i use multitor and there is his own etc folder at my Onion/multitor/etc, why this file message pop up at /etc/tor folder, when im just simple run command systemctl start tor. How to check deeply the truth about that message? Some reverse engineering technqiue ?
